# Postgresql / postgres 11 - "pipe broken" to remote server while running \copy command

Tags: postgresql

While running a \copy FROM import command in psql on a remote server I lost network connection (pipe broken)

The 8 GB CSV data file was supposed to be imported in a dedicated tablespace.

After this broken pipe, I see data in the dedicated tablespace (7.5 GB) and also a lot of data usage in the default tablespace (19 GB).

A select count(*) of the table return 0 rows.

How can I "rollback" this failed attempt to import data using \copy, so disk allocation in the 2 tablespaces are clean up ?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't reclaim the disk space lost automatically, due to how MVCC works. You should first [find the bloated objects](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat), then you have a few options:

- first is `VACUUM FULL` on found objects. Note that this will block the access to the object during the operation,
- install a `pg_repack` extension and try to "repack" the objects. This will effectively create a copy of specified object, put trigger on existing object so no new data is lost and then switch the old with the new

Note that autovacuuming won't decrease the disk space used, it will just mark the unneeded rows as available for reuse.

Comment: Hi Boris,

The table in which data was attempted to import, are not even showing up when I run the SQL from "find the bloated object"

Running 
VACUUM FULL [the tablename in a dedicated tablespace]
..dosen't change the disk usage for the partition

Comment: You can also check the diskspace used directly in filesystem, which directory has gotten bigger, which files? Maybe the `pg_tmp` directory is getting filled up? You can match files to pgsql objects, check: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-filename-to-table/

Comment: Default tablespace
4.0K /pg-data/tablespaces/default/PG_11_201809051/pgsql_tmp
19G /pg-data/tablespaces/default/PG_11_201809051/16395
19G /pg-data/tablespaces/default/PG_11_201809051
19G /pg-data/tablespaces/default

Dedicated tablespace for table - returning 0 rows
7.5G /pg-data/tablespaces/table/2018/PG_11_201809051/16395
7.5G /pg-data/tablespaces/table/2018/PG_11_201809051
7.5G /pg-data/tablespaces/table/2018

Comment: Above was running $du -h
/pg-data/tablespaces/default/ usage should be < 1GB and 
/pg-data/tablespaces/table/2018/ should be less than 10 MB (0 rows)

Comment: Check which files take the most diskspace and identify which pgsql object they belong to, using above link.

Comment: Seems like my dedicated tablespace size have automatically reduced overnight. From 3 x 7.5 GB to now 3 x 32 KB

Comment: ..or maybe it was VACUUM FULL [the tablename in a dedicated tablespace] running in the background on the Postgres server ?! The command did complete immediately and didn't had any impact at first glance. Thx BorisS

Comment: yes, it may take some time before the changes are visible on the filesystem, disk usage wise